# IAT Hooking .NET Application

Tags: c++, c, .net, portable-executable

I'm currently trying to hook calls to win32 using IAT Hooking.

It does work perfectly fine for native x86 and x64 applications. However the import table for applications using the .NET framework seems to be empty, which prevents me from hooking any function. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Why do you think .NET libraries have an Import Table? They don't use imports, they have their own method of linking? And why are you trying to "hook calls" anyway?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.